# Get relative date in auto format using Luxon

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

Trying a simple code here using Intl library internally on top of Luxon here to get relative dates. If my current date is in `2 hours ago`, `in 2 hours`, etc, I want it to display `today`. Else, I want it to display `1 day ago` or `in 1 day`.

I have `numeric` set to `auto` but it doesn't seem to get picked up.

```
const {DateTime} = require('luxon');

console.log(DateTime.fromMillis(Date.now() - 10090909).toRelative({
    numeric: 'auto',
})); 

// Date.now - 10090909 is 2 hours ago,
// but output here comes out to be 0 days ago
// expected is today
```

Sources I m referring:

1. [Intl Relative Date API](https://v8.dev/features/intl-relativetimeformat)
2. [Luxon Relative Date](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetorelative)

Comment: Did you try using `.toRelativeCalendar()` instead of `.toRelative()`?

Comment: @YashJani editing in broad generic tags like "date" is not helpful - it doesn't improve the question meaningfully or help interested people to find it.

Comment: @DavidW—yes it does.

Comment: @cmolina Thanks. This works fine, however, if today is 1 October and I m parsing date let's say, just 1 day ago, then it will give result as `last month`.  I was hoping something like today, yesterday, 2 days ago, 5 days ago, 1 week ago, 3 weeks ago, 1 month ago. But this is also fine. Thanks :)

Comment: The ECMAScript [*Intl* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) isn't a library, it's a built–in object that has a number of constructors, one being [*DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat). The OP code doesn't use Intl, only Luxon.

Comment: @DavidW it is an valid keyword as per your question!

Comment: @YashJani My view is that few people are actually interested in "date" so the tag doesn't add much. However, it seems like other people disagree with me so you can probably ignore me.